# Row-major ordering in C as Command Line Argument

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, command-line-arguments, row-major-order

I need to pass in a 2D area (a matrix) from the command line through a txt file that looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

I'm using C and need to have it in row-major order, so I'm trying to do this:

```
int matrix[][] = argv[2]; // it is the second command line argument passed
```

This isn't working, is it because it needs to be a 1-dimensional array? Am I only allowed to use a regular 1D array for row-major ordering?
The error I'm getting is "array type has incomplete element type 'int[]' "

Comment: You need to read the file in a loop, assigning to the array elements. And you have to declare the size of the array.

Comment: Is argv[2] the name of your file?

Comment: *argv* is an array of pointer to char => argv[2] is a string (if there are enough argument), not a 2D array of _int_

Comment: When you're declaring a multimensional array, you have to specify the sizes of all but the first dimension, you can't use `[][]`.

Comment: What means "from the comment line through a txt file" ? As asked by stark is argv[2] the name of the file having the content you give in the question ? Is the 2D array always 5x5 ?

Comment: @bruno "comment line" is probably a typo for "command line".

Comment: Will it take in the text file as a singular long string or 25 strings? And yes, I meant "command" and also forgot the semicolon after argv[2] as Bruno pointed out. Good catch.

Comment: @George by pity for the moment answer to our questions rather than to ask question yourself, we need first to understand what you want to do and the context. What are the first and second arguments of the program ? Is the (probable) file contains always a 5x5 array (may be the first arg gives the size) ?

Comment: @bruno the file would be some arbitrarily named text file like input.txt or matrix.txt. This is for an assignment and I'm waiting on a response whether the input will always be 5x5, but let's assume so for the sake of simplicity.
I'm looking to take this txt file that contains a 2D array and use it as so in m C file in row-major ordering. I'm confused as to how this should be implemented.

Comment: if i'm understanding correctly, row-major is a linear, contiguous memory layout, but does that mean that 2d arrays are actually implemented as regular 1d arrays in C? or do we still use 2d arrays like in other languages. I guess that would be the bigger conceptual question I'm not getting

Comment: @George you can have both, if you use a 1D array you have to compute by yourself the position of each element in it

Comment: @George I put an example of implementation, and its execution based on what you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to do this:
>
> ```
> int matrix[][] = argv[2]
> ```
>
> This isn't working,

because this is invalid, out of the missing ';' :

- at least the second dimension must be given, this is why you have the error *array type has incomplete element type 'int[]'*
- *matrix* is a (wrongly defined) 2D array of *int* but in the best case *argv[2]* is an array of char :

  - if the program is called without argument *argv[2]* is undefined
  - if the program is called with one argument *argv[2]* is NULL
  - if the program is called with at least 2 argument *argv[2]* is the string containing the second arg

---

Considering *argv[2]* is the pathname of the file containing the 5x5 matrix the declaration of the matrix can be :

```
int matrix[5][5];
```

and you need to read the values in the file to set the matrix's content, you cannot directly map the txt file to *matrix*

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  FILE * fp;

  if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s ?? <file>\n", *argv);
    return -1;
  }
  else if ((fp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL) {
    perror("cannot open file");
    return -1;
  }
  else {
    int matrix[5][5];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
      for (j = 0; j != 5; ++j) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &matrix[i][j]) != 1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "invalid file for [%d][%d]\n", i, j);
          return -1;
        }
      }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    /* debug */
    for (i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
      for (j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
        printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
      putchar('\n');
    }

    putchar('\n');

    /* you can also use it as a 1D array */
    for (i = 0; i != 25; ++i) {
      printf("%d ", ((int *) matrix)[i]);
      if (i%5 == 4)
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out whatever f
0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: That makes much more sense, thanks for the help!
is fscanf(fp, "%d", &matrix[i][j]) != 1 the line that is responsible for reading the txt file into the matrix?

Comment: @George yes, in detail if there is a valid external representation of an int in the file at the position specified by the file descriptor *fp* may be after spaces (space, tab, newline ...)  the corresponding int is saved into *matrix[i][j]* the file descriptor progress after the int representation and 1 is return (1 because the format *"%d"* request to read 1 element), else *fp* does not progress in the file and  *matrix[i][j]* is not set and 0 or *EOF* is returned. I do not have to take care of the spaces and newline because the format *%d* bypass them before to (try to) read the number

Comment: thanks for the help! However the lines 
fprintf(stderr, "invalid file for [%d][%d]\n", i, j);   and also fclose are giving me segmentation faults. Once I comment them out everything runs. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @George what changes you did from my code ? For me you use larger max indexes (I mean more than 5) but you didn't changed the dimensions of the matrix => you write out of it with an undefined behavior => segmentation faults in your case

Comment: I took out the if and else if in the beginning because I was hitting the 
usage: ./a.out ?? <file>
statement. I'm passing in a file called matrix.txt as my command-line argument and that's all.
Edit: the matrix is still a 5x5 in my txt file

Comment: @George if the argument of the program is just the file you have to replace *argv[2]* by *argv[1]* from my code

Comment: thank you so much! changing to argv[1] and argc < 2 instead of < 3 did the job!

Comment: @George fine, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

As the answer of @bruno, you were wrong when declare the 2D array. I just propose one solution to get info from input file with double pointer (use it if you do not know the size of array before (number of lines, number of cols).

You can use `fgets` to get line by line in the text file. Then using the `strtok` function to separate the line by space. To get the integer value from string, you can use `atoi` function.

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char line[256];
    int ** matrix = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    if(!matrix)
        return -1;
    if (argc < 2) {
        return -1;
    // argv[1] is the name of input file, for example input.txt
    FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int row = 0, col;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        col = 0;
        matrix[row] = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if(!matrix[row])
            return -1;
        char * token = strtok(line, " ");

        while(token != NULL) {
             matrix[row][col] = atoi(token);
             token = strtok(NULL, " ");
             col++;
             // increase the size of each line after each loop
             matrix[row] = realloc(matrix[row], (col+1) * sizeof(int));
             if(!matrix[row])
                return -1;
        }
        row++;
        // increase size of matrix after each loop
        matrix = realloc(matrix, (row+1)*sizeof(int *));
        if(!matrix)
            return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The test:

```
#cat input.txt
0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0

./test input.txt
0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```